# Json Decoder Error when reading from JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-colaboratory

I am trying to read a JSON file(17MB) stored in the google drive into collaboratory. Here is the code:

```
import json
with open('GOOGLEDRIVE_FILEPATH/FILE_NAME.json',encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
  data=json.load(f)
```

But data=json.load(f) results in a JSONDecodeError:
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 177193 (char 177192)
The JSON file is of the format:

```
[{ "id":1,
    "name": "Joe" 
},{"id":2,
    "name": "Jane" },
.
.
{"id": xxx,
    "name": "xxx" }
]
```

What could be the possible reason for such an error?

Comment: What exactly is the error? It's clear that `json.load()` doesn't like it, but if you don't report the reason, we can't tell you anything more useful than that. The file contents, or a sample if it is long, would help. Please [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The file is too long to upload but this is the error: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 177193 (char 177192)

Comment: And how long is your file? If it is 177,193 bytes then it looks like you have a stray trailing character. If not, open the file in a text editor that reports the cursor offset from TOF (like Notepad++) and examine the JSON at that point. If you still can't tell what is wrong, [edit] your question to report the dozen or so lines before and after that point. And please don't use comments to amplify your question. The question should explain the problem fully without readers having to comb through comments to piece your intent together.

Comment: Odds are it simply isn't JSON (i.e. doesn't conform to the standard) and that's why it fails. Try a different decoder (e.g. `jq` commandline utility) to get a comparison. Depending on the structure, I wouldn't rule out the possibility that out-of-memory condition is the root cause. In any case, the answer to your question can easily be found by searching for the error message, similar questions come up almost daily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of your inputs, even I thought that the issue was due to the size earlier, but it is now resolved after the removal of the stray trailing character in between my data elements that creeped in during the JSON dump operation. It was not obvious at the beginning due to the large file size. The hint of examining the JSON in a text editor was quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing stray characters in the JSON file that crept into the file during the append operation.